# Create pfx certificate with a specific PublicKeyToken

Tags: c#, certificate, clickonce, publickeytoken

I've lost my pfx certificate file and i'm asking myself if i can create a new one with a specific PublicKeyToken.

Is that possible to do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public key have a mathematical relationship with the private key.

see this Wikipedia article "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography"

So with a specific public key you will get a specific private key

Comment: Thanks, i know there's a relation between them but is that possible to create a pfx certificate from the public key i have ?

Comment: Being able to do that would infere that you could get the private key just by having the public key. If this was possible the the private public key relation wouldn't be secure

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done, as mentioned by Anders Stubberup the public key has a relation to the private key. This is called an assymetrical cryptography, or public-key cryptography. Here the public key is used for encrypting data and the private key is used for decryption of the data.

Certificates are not generated with symmetric cryptography because then every users could make copies of the certificate and that could lead to false certificates and exploitation of those certificates.

A handy [link](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-cryptography.htm) to the workings of a ssl certificates and (a)symmetric encryption.

It would be best to generate another certificate and store the private key etc that are needed for generation of the certificate somewhere safe.